# Getting warnings in Webstorm when compiling Typescript that contained Angular2 imports

Tags: webstorm, angular, typescript1.6

I just took an example from here https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I've done all according to the quickstart manual.
But getting warnings in WebStorm console when my `app.ts` is compiling.

Here is details:

I am on Windows 8.1 x64, Webstorm 11.0.1

`app.ts`:

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 3 App</h1>'
})
class AppComponent { }
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceRoot": "/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I was placing `tsconfig.json` file to `app` folder and in the root.

The `app.ts` actually getting file compiled but getting warnings for some reason:

```
error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
error TS1205: Decorators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.
error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.
```

I've got typings included

My folders structure

[image]

**Edit:**

After I set `tsconfig.json` in settings the errors disappeared from `Typescript` window

[image]

but got errors in `Run` output and in code editor:
[image]

Have no issues with `tsconfig.json`:
[image]

UPDATE:

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript helped to switch to the `tsconfig.json`. Then I resolved the next issues by disabling Typescript watcher that I had enabled before manually: File -> Settings -> Tools -> File Watchers. Now with these settings everything is working fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5248) is related to your problem or not, but it worths a read.

Comment: I just wanted to add that lately I have been getting this even though I do have the right setting in my tsconfig and WS is pointing to that config file. For some reason I have to restart WS and then everything is fine again.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to go into File -> Settings in Webstorm. And then on the settings sidebar go to Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript.

Then in the TypeScript settings page there is a radio button option for `Set options manually` or `Use tsconfig.json`. Select the tsconfig option and then apply changes and close. Then webstorm should know to use the tsconfig options when compiling the TypeScript.

Comment: it is saying now: discovered `tsconfig.json` but I have such filing that it is not using it. Also I just added secton `"exclude": [ "node_modules" ]` but webstorm trying to build `node_modules` like a crazy

Comment: How have you structured the `excludes` property in your tsconfig? Is it an property after the `compilerOptions ` or is it set as a property inside the `compilerOptions`

Comment: I just restarted the Webstorm. The errors a gone in `TypeScript compiler` console window. But: thre is same warnings wtill appeared in `Run` output window and I've got same errors highlighted in the `app.ts` window.

Comment: I think my `tsconfig.json` is good. Just updated that above. Webstrom saying - `No Problems Found` so it is all good with that file.

Comment: @MarcHarry, that worked well with the addition of providing the typescript 2.0+ compiler which I installed, instead of the WebStorm bundled one (I had 1.8.1). In the `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript` `compiler` section, change the compiler version to the wanted typescript's lib. That solved my issue.

Comment: I had the same problem on osx with a validtsconfig.json inside webstorm 2016.3.2 and I just had to restart the IDE

Comment: There is no radio button in newer versions.